# SSAS linked measure group and non related role playing dimensions between measure groups

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, cube

I have two measure groups.. each in its own seperate cubes...

Population_cube
 1) population_yearly
 date_id
 population_ct

2) medical_cases
 begin_care_date_id
 end_care_date_id

I have the following date dimensions
 3) dim_date
 date_id
 calendar_dt
 calendar_yr_nr
 calenar_mont_nr
 fiscal_year_nr
 fiscal_month_nr

4) dim_begin_care_date
 begin_care_date_id
 begin_care_calendar_dt
 begin_care_calendar_yr_nr
 begin_care_calendar_mont_nr
 begin_care_fiscal_year_nr
 begin_care_fiscal_month_nr

5) dim_end_care_date
 end_care_date_id
 end_care_calendar_dt
 end_care_calendar_yr_nr
 end_care_calendar_mont_nr
 end_care_fiscal_year_nr
 end_care_fiscal_month_nr

I created two named queries in my cube dsv and then created two cube dimensions off of that named  dim_begin_care_date_yr and dim_end_care_date_yr.  There is also the generice dim_date dimension defined for the population cube. I created the two named query based dimensions so that I could name the attributes according to their useage.  All 3 dimensions are based off of the same original view v_dim_date.

The problem is when I include the population measure group as a linked measure group in my medical_cases cube it thinks it is using seperate dimensions and I cannot then slice and dice the medical_case cube including the population_ct based on dim_begin_care_date.begin_care_calendar_yr_nr as I get the full population_ct as it does not split the population_ct by the year as it thinks it is a different dimension.

How do I use linked measure groups and role playing dimensions with appropriatley named attributes to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to use two different cubes? I just would use one cube with different measure groups, avoiding the need to use a linked measure group at all. In Analysis Services, you can have several measure groups in a cube without problems.

Comment: Yes, the population cube already exists and I don't want to have to duplicate it and all of its records as MOLAP cube, in addition to having to reprocess all of the data twice and maintain the population cube in two configurations.

I already have multiple measure groups in the cube, in fact, that is how it is now, a seperate measure group for populations from its fact table but it duplicates all of the population data and processing time as we already have population cube.

Comment: Have you considered making the population cube available instead as a perspective (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175338.aspx) of the combined cube?